# R anesrake issue with list names non-binary argument

Tags: r

I am using anesrake to weight some survey data, but am getting a non-binary argument error.  The error only occurs after I have added the names to the list to use as targets:

```
gender1<-c(0.516166000986901,0.483833999013099)
age<-c(0.15828262425613,0.364861110549873,0.429947760183493,0.0469085050104993)

mylist<-list(gender1,age)

names(mylist)<-c("gender1","age")
result<-anesrake(mylist,france,caseid=france$caseid, iterate=TRUE)

Error in x + weights : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In anesrake(targets, france, caseid = france$caseid, iterate = TRUE) :
  Targets for age do not sum to 100%. Adjusting values to total 100%
```

This also says that the targets for age don't add to 100%, which they do, so also not sure what that's about.  If I leave out the names(mylist) bit, I get the following error, presumably because R doesn't know which variables to use, but not a non-binary error:

```
Error in selecthighestpcts(discrep1, inputter, pctlim) : 
  No variables are off by more than 5 percent using the method you have chosen, either weighting is unnecessary or a smaller pre-raking limit should be chosen.
```

The variables in the data frame are called the same as the targets in the list, and are numeric:

```
> str(france)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   993 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Gender :Classes 'labelled', 'numeric'  atomic [1:993] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Gender"
 $ Age2   : num  2 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 ...
 $ gender1: num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ caseid : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ age    : num  2 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 ...
```

I have also tried converting gender1 and age to factor variables (as the numbers represent levels of each variable - gender has 2, age has 4), but with the same result.  I have used anesrake before successfully, so there must be something I am missing, but cannot see it!  Any help greatly appreciated....

Comment: Ah, think I've got it - there's an issue with the structure of the dataframe itself.  Even though the variables are numeric within it, the class tbl_df and tbl in the dataframe appear to be causing the problem.  When I run: 'france2<-as.data.frame(france[,c(3,5)])' and then rerun with france2, all works well.  For reference this has been caused by using haven to read in an SPSS file, which has brought across odd structures...

Comment: The `foreign` package has a `read.spss` function which reads in a data.frame. Note sure how up-to-date it is. It's support for Stata (`read.dta`) stopped with Stata 12 (2014 or so).

Comment: Thanks lmo - I think the package is getting a little out of date, and tends to introduce some of it's own issues when reading in the data - it's why I switched to haven! Lesson learned...

Comment: Hadley and crew are pushing the use of tibbles as a data.frame replacement. This is likely why `haven` reads in this format by default. Unfortunately, tibbles break some of the behavior of data.frames and packages that are not "tibbly-aware" are likely to not work properly.

Comment: That probably explains why the variables worked perfectly well as numerics in other R operations, but specifically not in anesrake. Thanks for the tip off!